# How do I keep Spyne from wrapping my response?

Tags: python, xml, soap, spyne

Here is the sample service

```
NS = 'my_app_namespace'

class MyMethodRS(ComplexModel):
    __tns__ = NS
    Version = XmlAttribute(Unicode)

class MyService(ServiceBase):
    __tns__ = NS

    @srpc(Unicode, _returns=MyMethodRS, _out_variable_name='MyMethodRS')
    def my_method(foo):
        response = MyMethodRS()
        response.Version = '1.0'
        return response

# and then application will be created and starged as wsgi app
```

Then I post a request

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
  <soap:Body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <my_method xmlns="my_app_namespace">
      <foo>bar</foo>
    <my_method>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And I got

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<senv:Envelope>
  <senv:Body>
    <tns:my_methodResponse>
      <tns:MyMethodRS Version="1.0" />
    </tns:my_methodResponse>
  </senv:Body>
</senv:Envelope>
```

I don't want response to be wrapped into `my_methodResponse`. I tried to add `_body_style='bare'` to `@srpc` and got the fail

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<senv:Envelope>
  <senv:Body>
    <senv:Fault>
      <faultcode>senv:Client.SchemaValidationError</faultcode>
      <faultstring><string>:14:0:ERROR:SCHEMASV:SCHEMAV_CVC_TYPE_3_1_2: Element '{http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05}my_method': Element content is not allowed, because the type definition is simple.</faultstring>
      <faultactor />
    </senv:Fault>
  </senv:Body>
</senv:Envelope>
```

How should I deal with it? I am trying to implement strict API and cannot add any wrappers to my responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from this request:

```
<my_method xmlns="my_app_namespace">
  <foo>bar</foo>
<my_method>
```

You need this:

```
class MyMethodRequest(ComplexModel):
    foo = Unicode

class MyService(ServiceBase):
    @srpc(MyMethodRequest, _returns=MyMethodRS, _body_style='bare' 
                           _out_variable_name='MyMethodRS')
    def my_method(request):
        foo = request.foo
        response = MyMethodRS()
        response.Version = '1.0'
        return response
```

Which is very close to what the non-bare mode actually does.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The *bare* definition seems clearer for me, because it have distinct request model description.

Comment: Whatever floats your boat :)

Comment: The problem here is ``_body_style='bare' `` only accepts one parameter.  and it sometimes fails in wsdl validation for some clients.  Is there any other way?

Comment: In bare mode, there is no room for another parameter. If that function needs more data, it needs to go inside that one parameter.

Comment: As for WSDL failures, please file an issue at the github repo so I can have a look