# How to model SOAP remote procedure attribute in spyne?

Tags: python, soap, spyne

I have the following SOAP Request, that I should be able to handle:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <LogoutNotification xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:sp:notify" type="global">
      <SessionID>
        _d5628602323819f716fcee04103ad5ef
      </SessionID>
    </LogoutNotification>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

SessionID is simply the RPC parameter. That's easy to handle.

But how can I model the `type` attribute in spyne? `type` is either "global" or "local".

I currently have the following (and disabled validation to be able to simply ignore the attribute):

```
class LogoutNotificationService(Service):
    @rpc(MandatoryUnicode, _returns=OKType,
         _in_variable_names={'sessionid': 'SessionID'},
         _out_variable_name='OK',
         )
    def LogoutNotification(ctx, sessionid):
        pass # handle the request
```

For sake of completeness here are the used models:

```
class OKType(ComplexModel):
    pass


class MandatoryUnicode(Unicode):
    class Attributes(Unicode.Attributes):
        nullable = False
        min_occurs = 1
```

The schema is [online](https://github.com/craigpg/shibboleth-sp2/blob/master/schemas/shibboleth-2.0-sp-notify.xsd). But there is no official WSDL for this containing the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The key to this is using the `bare` body style. Then you can (and need to) model the complete input and output message.

My working code looks like this:

```
class OKType(ComplexModel):
    pass


class MandatoryUnicode(Unicode):
    class Attributes(Unicode.Attributes):
        nullable = False
        min_occurs = 1


class LogoutRequest(ComplexModel):
    __namespace__ = 'urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:sp:notify'
    SessionID = MandatoryUnicode
    type = XmlAttribute(Enum("global", "local", type_name="LogoutNotificationType"))


class LogoutResponse(ComplexModel):
    __namespace__ = 'urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:sp:notify'
    OK = OKType


class LogoutNotificationService(Service):
    @rpc(LogoutRequest, _returns=LogoutResponse, _body_style='bare')
    def LogoutNotification(ctx, req):
        # do stuff, raise Fault on error
        # sessionid is available as req.SessionID
        return LogoutResponse
```

The (not really related question) about [not wrapping response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19536282/1381638) contains good examples and showed me how to solve this problem.