# Spyne server with complex input

Tags: python, xml, server, spyne

I am trying to write a simple python server using Spyne,
I have gone over the `hello world` examples, and now trying to do something a bit more sophisticated. Sadly, there are little to no examples for this (or at least, I couldn't find anything helpful)

I am sending the following XML to the server:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ObjectA xmlns="urn:SNSR_STD" ProtocolVersion="Undefined" MessageType="Undefined">
      <ObjectB>
        <field1>value1</field1>
        <field2>value2</field2>
        <field3/>
        <field4/>
        <field5/>
      </ObjectB>
    </ObjectA>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

My server service looks like that:
class ExampleService(ServiceBase):

```
@srpc(String, AnyXml, _returns=None)
def PrintObject(nothing, ObjectA):
    print ObjectA
```

And, trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514045/how-to-describe-element-attributes-with-spyne) question, I have created the following classes (although I am getting the same results without them):

```
namespace = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'


class ObjectB(ComplexModel):
    __namespace__ = namespace
    field1 = XmlAttribute(Unicode)
    field2 = XmlAttribute(Unicode)
    field3 = XmlAttribute(Unicode)
    field4 = XmlAttribute(Unicode)
    field5 = XmlAttribute(Unicode)


class ObjectA(ComplexModel):
    __namespace__ = namespace
    ObjectB = ObjectB
```

Unfortunately, I am getting a weird object which prints this: `<Element {my_application_tns}field1 at 0x431bee0>` and while debugging I can't seem to find any children (or whatever I need to go through all of the values).
I do have `value1` under the `text` field.

I tried to make the function get more `AnyXml` parameters, hoping I could read all of them - to no avail.
I also tried other values instead of `AnyXml`, such as `XmlData` and `XmlAttribute`, but it didn't work.

Using `XmlAttribute` I got an `AttributeError: type object 'XmlAttribute' has no attribute 'attribute_of'` from `spyne\model\complex.py, line 605, in __init__ a_of = v.attribute_of`.
Using `XmlData` I got an `AttributeError: type object 'XmlData' has no attribute 'type'` from `spyne\model\complex.py, line 119, in resolve_namespace cls.type.resolve_namespace(cls.type, default_ns, tags)`.

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks :)